# Programmatically create order with configurable product in magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, orders, magento2.2

The following code is working fine to create order programmatically with simple products. How can I write the code to create order with configurable products?

```
    if (file_exists($orderFile) && file_exists($orderItemFile)) {

                $orderData = $this->fileCsv->getData($orderFile);
                $orderItemData = $this->fileCsv->getData($orderItemFile);

                $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                    ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

                $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();

                $tableName = $this->_resources->getTableName('sequence_order_1');

                foreach ($orderData as $ordValue) {

                    if ($ordValue[0] != "ORD_ID" && $ordValue[2] != "ORD_VEC_ID") {

                        $orderData = [
                            'currency_id'  => 'USD',
                            'email'        => $ordValue[6],
                            'shipping_address' =>[
                                'firstname'    => $ordValue[14], //address Details
                                'lastname'     => $ordValue[15],
                                'street' => $ordValue[16],
                                'city' => $ordValue[17],
                                'country_id' => $ordValue[18],
                                'region_id' => $ordValue[19],
                                'region' => $ordValue[19],
                                'postcode' => $ordValue[20],
                                'telephone' => $ordValue[21],
                                'fax' => $ordValue[22],
                                'save_in_address_book' => 1
                            ]
                        ];
                        foreach ($orderItemData as $oriValue){

                            if ($oriValue[0] != "ORI_ID" && $oriValue[1] == $ordValue[0]) {

                                $sku = $oriValue[3];
                                $_product = $blockInstance->getProductBySku($sku);
                                $productId = $_product->getEntityId();

                                $productItem[] = ['product_id'=>$productId,'qty'=>$oriValue[4],'price'=>$oriValue[22]];

                            }
                        }
                        $orderData['items'] = $productItem;

                        $sql = "ALTER TABLE " . $tableName . " AUTO_INCREMENT=".$ordValue[0];
                        $connection->query($sql);

                        $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
                        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
                        $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
                        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                        $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address

                        if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
                            //If not avilable then create this customer
                            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                                ->setStore($store)
                                ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                                ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                                ->setEmail($orderData['email'])
                                ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
                            $customer->save();
                        }

                        $cart_id = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart();
                        $cart = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart_id);
                        $cart->setStore($store);

                        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
                        $cart->setCurrency();
                        $cart->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
                        //add items in quote
                        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
                            $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($item['product_id']);
                            $cart->addProduct(
                                $product,
                                intval($item['qty'])
                            );
                        }
                        //Set Address to quote @todo add section in order data for seperate billing and handle it
                        $cart->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
                        $cart->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

                        $shippingAddress = $cart->getShippingAddress();
                        //@todo set in order data
                        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                            ->collectShippingRates()
                            ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate'); //shipping method
                        //$cart->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($this->rate);

                        $cart->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
                        //@todo insert a variable to affect the invetory

                        $cart->setInventoryProcessed(false);
                        // Set sales order payment

                        $cart->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
                        // Collect total and saeve

                        $cart->collectTotals();
                        // Submit the quote and create the order
                        $cart->save();

                        $cart = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart->getId());
                        $orderId = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($cart->getId());

                        $order = $this->order->load($orderId);

                        $shippingAmount = $ordValue[27];
                        $discountAmount = $ordValue[34];

                        $order->setCreatedAt($ordValue[4]);

                        $order->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
                        $order->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
                        $order->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
                        $order->setBaseDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
                        $order->setGrandTotal(($order->getSubTotal()+$shippingAmount)-$discountAmount);

                        $order->save();

                        $order->setEmailSent(0);

                        if($order->getEntityId()){
                            $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
                        }else{
                            $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
                        }

                        echo $orderId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have to add the following code to create order with configurable products.

```
                $atrCodes = array(93=>18,177=>14); //93:color attribute id, 18:attribute option id likewise next is for size

                if($productType == 'configurable'){
                    $objParam = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                        [
                            'product' => $productId, //configurable product id
                            'selected_configurable_option' => 2, //selected simple product id
                            'qty' => 1,
                            'super_attribute' => $atrCodes
                        ]
                    );
                }

                $cart->addProduct($product, $objParam);
```